# problemas con .map en una tabla

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, tablas

estoy haciendoun componente de tabla pero tengo un error, a este le pasare un array pero cuando se lo paso asi:

```
const content = [
  ["#", "Daniel", "Abrego"],
  ["#", "Daniel", "Abrego"]
]
```

me aparece todo mal:

este seria el codigo de esa parte de la tabla :

```
<tbody>
        {content.map((cell, index) => (
          <tr className="h-3 border-b" style={{ borderColor: "#E0E0E0" }}>
            <td className="px-3 py-3">{cell}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como bien te han dicho, estás recorriendo tu `array` `content` pero no cada uno de los `arrays` internos. Es decir, ese `map` inicial sería para las rows (`<tr>`) y tendrías que tener otro para las celdas (`<td>`)

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  const content = [["#", "Daniel", "Abrego"], ["#", "Daniel", "Abrego"]];

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {content.map((row, index) => (
            <tr
              className="h-3 border-b"
              key={index}
              style={{ borderColor: "#E0E0E0" }}
            >
              {row.map((cell, i) => (
                <td className="px-3 py-3" key={i}>
                  {i === 0 ? index : cell}
                </td>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Te dejo [aquí](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-b7xyxx) el ejemplo funcionando